# Facebook share button without application id in html

Tags: facebook

i want to add share not like button where i can post the image of my action and the name of it without creating application on Facebook i want to use it within my html page where it shows my a pop up dialog to set the message i want but not via an application

Answer (score 1):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

What happened to the old Share button?
We deprecated the Share Button when we launched the Like button, because the Like button improves clickthrough rates by allowing users to connect with one click, and by allowing them to see which of their friends have already connected. For reference, the Share button documentation is still available here.